# Why $\gamma^5$ pseudoscalar transforms with a determinant?

Tags: special-relativity, dirac-matrices

In the Dirac matrices we define $\gamma^5$ matrix, which transforms like

$\bar{\psi}' \gamma^5 \psi'=\bar{\psi} S^{-1} \gamma^5 S \psi=det(a) \bar \psi \gamma^5 \psi$

I try the following:

$\bar{\psi}' \gamma^5 \psi'=\bar{\psi} i S^{-1} \gamma^0 \gamma^1 \gamma^2 \gamma^3 S \psi$

$\bar{\psi}' \gamma^5 \psi'=\bar{\psi} i S^{-1} \gamma^0 S S^{-1} \gamma^1 S S^{-1} \gamma^2 S S^{-1} \gamma^3 S \psi$

Now, $S^{-1}\gamma^{\mu}S=a^\mu_v \gamma^v$ ($a_v^\mu$ - Lorentz $matrix element). Thus:

$S^{-1} \gamma^5 S=a^0_\mu a^1_\nu a^2_\lambda a^3_\alpha i \gamma^\mu  \gamma^\nu  \gamma^\lambda \gamma^\alpha$

Now it looks almost like what I need - just rearrange gammas on the rhs to put them in the order 0,1,2,3 - this involves the inversions (which change sign due to commutation rules), required in the permutation definition of determinant. So, everything is almost fine. Except for: this sum will display also repeated indices in $\gamma$ (and so lower indices of $a$ as well). E.g. terms like $a_0^0 a_0^1 a_0^2 a_0^3\gamma^0 \gamma^0 \gamma^0 \gamma^0$ which should not appear in the determinant sum! (I can't even build $\gamma^5$ in such terms) How can I **make them vanish**?

Identical gammas in a product form an unit matrix (or negative unit matrix), but it seems not to help in cancelling out these terms.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I traced this down. The idea was close to the right one, but I should have started with different representation of $\gamma^5$. Namely,

$\gamma^5=i\gamma^0\gamma^1\gamma^2\gamma^3=-\frac{i}{4!} \epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} \gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma$

Where $\epsilon$ is the antisymmetric tensor, which takes value 0 if any two indices repeat, "-1" for even permutation of indices, "+1" for odd permutation of indices. We can formulate $\gamma^5$ this way because depending on the permutation parity, the product of $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma^\rho\gamma^\sigma$ due to commutation rules can be rearranged into $\gamma^0\gamma^1\gamma^2\gamma^3$ with a sign alternating exactly according to $\epsilon$. Thus summing over indices give 4! identical contributions of $\gamma^5$. Having this identity, we write the transformation:

$S^{-1}\gamma^5S=-\frac{i} {4} \epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}S\gamma^\mu S^{-1}S \gamma^\nu S^{-1}S \gamma^\rho S^{-1}S \gamma^\sigma S^{-1}$

$S^{-1}\gamma^5S=-\frac{i} {4} \epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}a^\mu_\alpha a^\nu_\beta a^\rho_\gamma a^\sigma_\delta\gamma^\alpha \gamma^\beta \gamma^\gamma \gamma^\delta$

Here it is now possible to introduce the det(a) after short observation. By definition:

$det(a)=\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} a_0^\mu a_1^\nu a_2^\rho a_3^\sigma$

(common permutation definition of determinant). Now here we could start from a different reference permutation than 0123. Starting from $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta$, the sign for all terms in the summation will change by $\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}$, i.e.:

$\epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}det(a)=\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} a_\alpha^\mu a_\beta^\nu a_\gamma^\rho a_\delta^\sigma$

Substituting in transformation formula:

$S^{-1}\gamma^5S=-\frac{i} {4} \epsilon_{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} det(a) \gamma^\alpha \gamma^\beta \gamma^\gamma \gamma^\delta=det(a)\gamma^5$

i.e. the desired result that enters between the wavefunctions.